# Event notification on BROKER_QUEUE_DISABLED not being received

Tags: sql, events, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

In SQL Server 2008 R2 i have setup a Service Broker sending, outbound and a notification queue. The outbound queue has activation enabled.

I am looking to catch the BROKER_QUEUE_DISABLED notification when a poison message causes the outbound queue to be disabled. I am however not able to catch the notification on the notification queue - what could be wrong?

```
CREATE QUEUE [dbo].[NotificationQueue]

CREATE SERVICE [dbo_NotificationService]
    ON QUEUE [dbo].[NotificationQueue]
    ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification])

CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION [cont_OutboundEvent]
    ON QUEUE [cont].[OutboundQueue]
    FOR BROKER_QUEUE_DISABLED 
    TO SERVICE 'dbo_NotificationService', 'current database'
```

Comment: Do you mean the `[OutboundQueue]` get disabled, but no messages arrives in `[NotificationQueue]`? Follow the steps at http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/ , and/or attach [`ssbdiagnose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934450.aspx), repro the issue and see what the diag tool says.

Comment: Yes, it is the outbound queue that gets disabled and where i would like to catch the notification. The outbound queue has activation enabled. The activation calls a procedure that tries to deliver the message on the queue to an MQ. If it is not able to get an OK (200) response from the MQ it rolls back the transaction. When it reaches the 5-try limit it disables the queue and this is when i would like to catch a notification. I am forcing the activation procedure to fail by disabling the MQ. When the MQ is enabled messages are flowing through to the MQ as expected.